# Creating GUI as the main class in the project in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

As the University project, I have to make a simple program in Java and I am currently using the latest version of Netbeans IDE 8.0.2.

I know that main class is where our program will begin and when I am creating classes, I make a mistake but I do not know where..

My program mainly consists of 3 classes and User interface.

ATM - ATMCard - Account

my questions,

1. ATM should the main class and the GUI. How can I create such class in Netbeans? I mean, as the options, there are Java Main class or other forms.
2. Should GUI be separated from main class ? I mean, in total, should there be 4 classes (GUI - ATM - ATMCard - Account)

I can guess that these are very simple questions but it is important since I will build all the program on the structure, which is shaped by your answers..

Thank you in advance..

Comment: There are many tutorials about this subject, check out https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-functionality.html for example or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Comment: 1.No ATM shouldn't be the MainClass and GUI.
2.Yes GUI should be seprated from MainClass.

Comment: @Ken you can create ATM as your MainClass but then that not a good pracice

Comment: @Abhi thank you very much for the answer. I will follow your instructions. As Kiki´s answer. I will create ATM as the main class and call the form from this class..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In netbeans i normaly create new Java project.

```
(File -> New project -> Java -> Java Application)
```

And select the project's name. There is an option where you can selec option create main class.

Next i normaly create two packages. For instance in your case it could be: 
`atm.gui` (for gui) package and `atm.bl` package (for buisness logic).

Then select gui package and left click on it, select new JFrame form (AtmForm or something).
And in jour main class just call:

```
AtmForm form = new AtmForm();
form.setVisible(true);
```

So the structure should look like this:

[image]